# Save commandline commands for Python

Tags: command-line, bash, python

I have a tool that's in Python- it resides in a git repository.

Whenever this tool is started (say, $mytool start is the command that starts the tool)- I want to save all the following command line commands in a history file in the current directory.

unix terminal/shell:

```
   $pwd
   $xyx
   $mytool start
   $abc
   $abc1
   $abc2
```

In the history.txt should have:

```
   $mytool start
   $abc
   $abc1
   $abc2
```

What code can I add in my tool (in Python) to save the cmdline commands (not the cmdline output) in a file?

Comment: To save all the output on the terminal, you could use  [`script(1)` utility](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is already done for you by bash history. Its stored in .bash_history in your home dir

Comment: I know about bash history and this is not what I want. I only want a portion of the commandlines to be saved, the ones that are related to mytool, so that if someone else pulls my repo, they get my command history.

Comment: so open the file in python and take out the bits you need then put them in your log file